# Redirecting URL using GetHTMLElement in NiFi

Tags: html, apache-nifi

I have fetched the next url from an HTML page using GetHTTP and GetHTMLElement processor in NiFi. How do I use this fetched URL in another GetHTMLElement processor, because it does not take or consider attributes from its previous processor.

Version of NiFi:NiFi 1.1.1

Any answers would be helpful at the earliest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could send the URL to an InvokeHttp processor which supports incoming flow files and you can set the "Remote URL" to expression language like "${HTMLElement}" or whatever the attribute name is where the url is.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
But after I fetch the next page URL ,I need to go to that page extract some data from it and also the next page URL from it.For this I need a GetHTMLElement processor.
How do I use GetHTMLElement processor to fetch the next URL again?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Bryan Bende,

I extracted the next url by setting the base URL and setting Attribute name as abs:href in GetHTMLElement and sent it to InvokeHTTP processor.Then I looped back the output of InvokeHTTP to the previous GetHTMLElement to extract further next URLs.

Setting Attribute name as abs:href in GetHTMLElement helps in forming the proper URL.In my case it helped in forming the full URL as:

```
www.abc.com/extracted_next_url
```

My base URL was:

```
www.abc.com
```

Thanks